# 500 error when using zerotier to join the network on Ubuntu-in-termux

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, vpn

Initially, I wanted to use zerotier on termux, but I soon encountered errors and realized that termux was not well compatible with zerotier, so I used Ubuntu-in-termux as a replacement.

To install zerotier on Ubuntu-in-termuxs, I tried to execute the download command directly in it, but it reported an error saying that I needed to execute with non-sudoer privileges, so I created a normal user and tried again to install zerotier.

After adding a normal user, I used the official `curl -s https://install.zerotier.com | sudo bash` command and got an error when starting the service at the install process end.

My ubuntu version is

```
Linux localhost 4.14.116 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 9 22:12:36 CST 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

My processor info in ubuntu-in-termux is

```
Processor       : AArch64 Processor rev 0 (aarch64)
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 3.84
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 atomics fphp asimdhp cpuid asimdrdm lrcpc dcpop asimddp
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0xd05
CPU revision    : 0
```

Here is the error output when installing zerotier:

```
- ** ZeroTier Service Quick Install for Unix-like Systems
- ** Tested OSes / distributions:
- ** MacOS (10.13+) (just installs ZeroTier One.pkg)
*** Debian Linux (7+)
*** RedHat/CentOS Linux (6+)
*** Fedora Linux (16+)
*** SuSE Linux (12+)
*** Mint Linux (18+)
- ** Supported architectures vary by OS / distribution. We try to support
*** every system architecture supported by the target.
- ** Please report problems to [contact@zerotier.com](mailto:contact@zerotier.com) and we will try to fix.
- ** Detecting Linux Distribution
- ** Found Ubuntu, creating /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zerotier.list
Hit:1 [http://download.zerotier.com/debian/jammy](http://download.zerotier.com/debian/jammy) jammy InRelease
.....
Get:5 [http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports) jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Fetched 229 kB in 3s (70.1 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
gpg is already the newest version (2.2.27-3ubuntu2.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
- ** Installing zerotier-one package...
security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
zerotier-one
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3338 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9669 kB of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package zerotier-one.
(Reading database ... 109794 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../zerotier-one_1.10.5_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking zerotier-one (1.10.5) ...
Setting up zerotier-one (1.10.5) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/zerotier-one.service → /lib/systemd/system/zerotier-one.service.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
- ** Enabling and starting ZeroTier service...
Synchronizing state of zerotier-one.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable zerotier-one
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
- ** Package installed but cannot start service! You may be in a Docker
*** container or using a non-standard init service.
```

Apparently, there was an error when starting the zerotier service in the last step of the installation. When I tried to ignore the error for the zerotier-cli join operation, it returned`500 join {}`and failed.

When I then tried to do a debug search for *zerotier Failed to connect to bus: Host is down* and *zerotier 500 join{}*  keywords, most of the results were for me to fix the zerotier service, which I did, including changing the zerotier-one. service and changing the port. But it still didn't fix the problem.

My goal is to create a virtual desktop on Android using ubuntu-in-termux, and use zerotier to network it so that other devices (Hololens) can access it.

*ps. I am sorry that my English is not very good and this text was translated using a machine, I would appreciate if you could understand.*